# PHP RegEx Replace All URLs That Aren't Images

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I'm currently using this regular expression to capture all URLs in a string, which could be multiple lines and contain any other sort of text, which is working perfectly for normal URLs. But I want to replace image URLs in a different way, so my current expression can't match those URLs.

My current expression is

```
(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)
```

But I don't want it to match URLs that end with (jpe?g|png|gif), and I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to use the RegEx negative lookaheads.

Comment: Really, it would be easier to just check the urls afterwards by matching all urls and then checking them. Or use preg_replace_callback which would allow you to check additional stuff on the match and add additional logic to check what type of url it is. But, if you wanted to use a single regex, put something like this at the start of your pattern: `(?!\S+(?:png|gif|jpe?g))` which will force a url to not match if it has `.(png|gif|jpe?g)` anywhere in the string. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/bA4iO5/1)

Comment: Yep that, did it. I was almost there, but I didn't try the very beginning of that string, but that worked perfectly. I might have to look into that other function you mentioned though, as I was unaware of such a function, but it sounds like I'd have a lot more control and power over what I'm doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, it would be easier to just check the urls afterwards by matching all urls and then checking them. Or use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) which would allow you to check additional stuff on the match and add additional logic to check what type of url it is. You just switch the replacement value with a callback and whatever is returned from the callback is what is replaced.

But, if you wanted to use a single regex, put something like this at the start of your pattern: `(?!\S+(?:png|gif|jpe?g))` which will force a url to not match if it has `.(png|gif|jpe?g)` anywhere in the string.